# Should I post questions regarding the C#-bindings of GDAL on StackOverflow or Geographic Information Systems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding the C#-bindings of GDAL. I found similar topics on StackOverflow as well as on Geographic Information Systems (StackExchange). What would be the best way to go here, posting it in both forums?

Comment: If it's about a C# problem, post on StackOverflow. If it's about a GDAL problem, post on GIS. Whatever you do, though, don't post it on both.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, posted it on GIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to formulate the question, during that process you will probably develop a feeling for where the question should be posted.

Once you post the question, it may turn out that the other SE page is more suitable then the question can be migrated.

As said in the comment, do not post in both.